# Are there any Operating Systems that allow adding/removing of CPU/RAM without rebooting?

Tags: memory, cpu, operating-systems, cloud, cloud-computing

I'm exploring Cloud Computing. The first thing you get to learn is horizontal/vertical scaling. In horizontal scaling you simply add a new server (image) to your existing servers. In vertical scaling you add new hardware (CPU/RAM) to your same server.

Then you read something like "most Operating Systems don't allow adding hardware without rebooting"

So my question is: ***Are there any Operating Systems that would allow me to add RAM for example without rebooting***?

Comment: You can do that to a virtual OS (VM) but not a real OS.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm playing with Oracl Virtual Box. And while my image is running, I can't add RAM or CPU cores. Or are there other VM managers that allow you to add RAM/CPU while running?

Comment: VirtualBox doesn't support it but other hypervisors actually do

Comment: I think bigger players have so much vertical scaling, that it doesn't matter and most bigger players also have a custom linux, built from ground up and keeping in mind to support hot swapping, I think it goes by something, that pc is given a notice to empty up memory from stick 3 and then swappeed, but i belive you need to swap them one by one, leaving at least 1 stick in.

Comment: @Ramhound please check Andrew Lamarra's answer and let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: @KristoferVesi  thanks for the answer. But do you mean by bigger players incorporates like Google for example? I mean do you think that Google/Facebook for example go with vertical scaling rather than horizontal? Kindly clarify. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ramhound may I ask why this question is put on hold? I'm not seeking product recommendations or something like that. I'm just wondering if a certain feature is available in operating systems.

Comment: @AhmedWas your question is asking "are there any operating systems" which is very much bordering on asking for "products that do x" (i.e. a product recommendation). Even if you aren't asking for products and looking at it the other way you are asking for a list of things. Lists of things do not work well in the Q&A format where we expect a solid solution to a problem and are generally considered to be too broad. It would be better to ask if there are any real technical reasons *why* an operating system might not support hotswapping RAM.

Comment: @AhmedWas - I think the answer you got is commentary.  I also think none of the hypervisors used have this feature so it's not shocking the user wasn't successful.  Additionally, as pointed out, the only question you asked for a recommendation for an os. OS is software, thus, your asking for a software recommendation.  (You could easily solve this catch-22)

Comment: @AhmedWas I can't really bring examples, but it goes something near this: you host on your box, get a server, get servers, at that point, there is just shutting down, but if you have 100+ then it solves fast, because shutting down isn't a big problem in 1/100 when at first it was 1/1 or 1/2 and the bigger companies (Google is the bold big, I would say bigger companies, what are known by most internet or a bit less than most go under it) the efficiency plays a role, so then you start to develop a HSwappable OS, but such as Google, it doesn't matter anymore, since --...--

Comment: --...-- the solution is so compact, they can't change it and in order to remove a tiny box from the rack, they need to remove power, so they just say shut down node a6889k or something and take it out, you can google for google datacenter, they are truly small [notice here, that the power comes from next to rack and they pull it out completly?](https://youtu.be/XZmGGAbHqa0) somehow timestamp link didn't work, it's 3:16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this on 3 hypervisors (VirtualBox, VMWare Workstation 12.5, and VMWare ESXi 6.0 via the Embedded Host Client) and several OS's (Windows Server 2k8, Windows 7, and Ubuntu Server 16.04). None of the hypervisor software would even give me the option to increase CPU's or RAM while the machines were running. Even if they gave me the option, I doubt the OS would take the change w/out a reboot.